# Unable to install 64-bit Pygame on Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pip, python-wheel

I have 64-bit python 3.4 installed, which comes with pip. I wanted to install pygame, and I know that the 32 bit version that they have on their site wouldn't work with my version of python. So I downloaded the 64-bit python 3.4 pygame package from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame) (pygame‑1.9.2a0‑cp34‑none‑win_amd64.whl). I renamed the package to `pygame.whl` and tried to use pip on the command line to install it, but it gave me this error;

```
Collecting pygame
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygame (from versions:
)
Some externally hosted files were ignored as access to them may be unreliable
(use --allow-external pygame to allow).
No matching distribution found for pygame
```

So I tried using the `--allow-external` option, but it gave me a different error and asked me to provide a requirements file. I looked around, and found that I might need to try using the `--pre` option, but it gave me the exact same error as above regardless. How can I install the package?

Comment: what os are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows 8.1

Comment: have a look here https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/downloads

Comment: I already stated in my post above, 32-bit versions of pygame don't work with 64-bit python. I've tried it before.

Comment: how did you try installing the .whl?

Comment: Silly question: did you download the 64-bit version of Pygame _for Python 3.4_?

Comment: Look at the file in my post; `pygame‑1.9.2a0‑cp34‑none‑win_amd64.whl`. If that isn't for python 3.4 then I don't know which one is.

Comment: True; my bad. Did you try `pip install C:\<full file path>\<original file name>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely reason you failed to install the `.whl` package is that you typed

```
pip install pygame
```

at the command prompt, instead of switching to the directory where you stored your renamed `pygame.whl` and running

```
pip install pygame.whl
```

`pip` requires that you give the *full name* of the file being installed.

The error message you got indicates that you ran the first command, and `pip` was looking in PyPI for `pygame` (which isn't there). The `--allow-external` command would have allowed you to specify a remote location where a source file or `.whl` file could be found.

In the future, I'd recommand *not* renaming the files downloaded from the (quite excellent) site you linked to, so that when you try to install them you're **sure** you're running the right command. Remember, you can always use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to complete file names on the command line.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up redownloading the file and running this command; `pip install "Downloads\pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl"`. It worked perfectly.